# An android application running in service mode can have User interface?

Tags: android, android-service, android-bluetooth

Currently i have a requirement like my application run only when bluetooth is on and it should communicate with other devices. Suppose if application is running in service mode can have user inteface? if yes the what about the battery and memory consumption

Comment: any UI must be done on main thread ( activity ) and any long process must be avoided from main thread ( services , asynctask etc.. ) u could anyways start an activity from service  and show interface...

Comment: You can have a usual app and define a service for Your purposes. For example, Your prior intention is the service, but You want to give the possibility for some settings. But You have to be carefull because of task managers or the android behaviour to kill services if space is needed. For sure a service will drain battery but this depends on what You will do inside the service. Also, You can define Your service as a foreground service to be more secure that this is not stopped (a foreground service could also be stopped, but it´s the last one that is touched by the system)..

Comment: Please provide any link which explaining in depth of this topic service mode